# nodejs will not enable corepack: operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, pnpm

I have installed nodejs and i am trying to enable corepack with `corepack enable` but it gives me this error on windows:

```
Internal Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\pnpm'
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\pnpm'
```

I can not find the pnpm folder is is refering to in the nodejs folder and i have tried to `npm install -g pnpm` which did install pnpm

how do I fix this?

Comment: Is this on windows or Linux?

Comment: sorry it is windows i will add it to the post

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Try running the cmd as administrator

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for me, i installed node via nvm on windows.

Comment: It seems it *has* to be a Command Prompt, too. An elevated PowerShell prompt didn't work for me but a Command Prompt did.

Comment: its not working for me, i tried running from administraotr. still  having the same error

Comment: @MaryamNaveed it should be another thing not related to permissions then ... Are you sure that's the error you're getting?

Comment: @Ikdemm yes same error

Comment: As an additional step I had to give FullControl permissions to "C:\Program Files\nodejs" folder for the current user. Only after this it worked.

Comment: Why is it necessary to run `corepack enable` as administrator?

Answer (score 1):

If running as administrator / changing permissions is unfeasible, corepack docs explains a [workaround](https://github.com/nodejs/corepack#corepack-enable--name) without admin privileges necessary.

```
echo "function yarn { corepack yarn `$args }" >> $PROFILE
echo "function yarnpkg { corepack yarnpkg `$args }" >> $PROFILE
echo "function pnpm { corepack pnpm `$args }" >> $PROFILE
echo "function pnpx { corepack pnpx `$args }" >> $PROFILE
echo "function npm { corepack npm `$args }" >> $PROFILE
echo "function npx { corepack npx `$args }" >> $PROFILE
```